# Remove custom target from Visual Studio CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, target

Is there a way in CMake to specify that a custom target not to be added to the Visual Studio solution? I have translation target for every component and this doubles the number of projects I see in Visual Studio

Comment: Have you considered to put it as a `POST_BUILD` step? Otherwise no, you can't hide targets. Just put it in a specific folder to make them less visible.

Comment: I need a custom target because I don't want to generate translation files and compile at the same time

Comment: Ok. What about 1 target for generating all translation files? Could you please give [mcve] of CMake code, then it would be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: I grouped all the translate targets in a single directory. That is ok for me now